# how to use variables in hosts specification in ansible playbooks and templates

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I can use variables in jinja2 template but I want to use variables in jinja2 template for loop hosts.

#### Example:

I have a variable `env`.
my template:

```
{% for i in groups.tag_ansible_group_{{ env }}_riak %}
  test{{ loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

Run:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml --extra-vars="env=prod"
```

But I am getting this error

```
TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [testlab-lan]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got '{'. String: {% for i in groups.tag_ansible_group_{{ env }}_riak %}\n  test{{ loop.index }}\n{% endfor %}"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/akhil/Projects/ansible-tendant/tests/test.retry
```

How to use variable `env` in hosts specification?
Is it possible?
If not then how to deploy my project into different environments without modifying templates everytime?
and also **if it's not possible then what is the use of using variables in hosts in a playbook?**

**Problem**
playbook.yml

```
- name: configure redis slaves
  hosts: tag_ansible_group_{{ env }}_redis_slave
  vars:
    - redis_slaveof: "{% for host in groups.keys()|select('match', 'tag_ansible_group_' + env + '_redis_master')|list %} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} 6379 {% endfor %}"
    - redis_version: 3.2.8
  roles:
    - redis
```

run:

```
ansible-playbook -i dynamic_inventories/test site.yml --extra-vars "env=test"
```

output:

```
TASK [redis : create redis config file] ******************************************************************************
fatal: [3.17.183.147]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: u\"hostvars['tag_ansible_group_test_redis_master']\" is undefined"}
fatal: [18.223.172.101]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: u\"hostvars['tag_ansible_group_test_redis_master']\" is undefined"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works

```
{% set grp = [ 'tag_ansible_group_' , env , '_riak' ]|join() %}

{% for host in groups.get(grp) %} 
    {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the *select* filter below

```
{% for i in groups.keys()|select('match', 'tag_ansible_group_' + env + '_riak')|list %}
```

Comment: getting some errors again after using your method.please check updated question.

Comment: In my example "*for i in groups.keys()*" variable "*i*" is the name of a **group**. Erroneously you used it as a **host**. "*hostvars[<name_of_group>]*"  is undefined, of course.

Comment: then how can i loop through hosts in matching groups...````{% for i in groups.keys()|select('match', 'tag_ansible_group_' + env + '_riak')|list %} {% for j in i } {{ hostvars['j']['some_fact'] }} ````...do i have to use 2 loops...this is making the templates complex...